# Subscription email subject does not show the site name

Tags: feature-request, subscription

Now it is `New $tag_name questions for $date - Stack Exchange`

Could you please replace 'Stack Exchange' with the site name — Stack Overflow, Server Fault etc? It's useful because  some tags exist in many sites.

Comment: What do you want to have happen for a multi-site filter?

Answer (score 1):

There is a technical problem here, since tag subscription is actually part of a more generic [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) which allows you to choose more than one site.

For example, [this filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/71488/c-on-stack-overflow-and-game-dev) takes questions from two sites. What you want to appear in the email subject in such case?

So I'd say just leave it as it is now.

Comment: 'What you want to appear in the email subject in such case?' - let it be 'on Stack Exchange (sites)'. Do you have statistic how many subscriptions exists which use more than one site at a time? My guess it is less than 5%